# Does this logic make sense? Property1 = Property1

Tags: .net, logic

My ASP.NET page has a lot of HTML elements that are visible/enabled based on conditions, for example:

```
Element1
Element3
Element5
```

visibility depends on let's say

```
Checkbox1
DateTime.Now
```

Does it make sense to encapsulate this in a property called SectionVisibility such that

```
private bool SectionVisibility
{
    get {condition1 && condition2 && etc...}
    set {element1, element2 etc... = value; }
}
```

and in Page_Load call `SectionVisibility = SectionVisibility`?

Assume that I have a lot of conditions.

Comment: It looks to me like there'd never be any point in setting the SectionVisibility - you could just expose the get method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't write code like this. It violates [POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise).
`SectionVisibility = SectionVisibility` looks like it doesn't do anything. And it should behave that way.

I would create a method called `CalculateSectionVisibility` (currently your getter) and one called `ApplySectionVisibility` (currently your setter).

If they are always used in combination you could squash them together into a method `UpdateSectionVisibility`.